# Reactor unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, project-reactor

I am new to the reactive world. I am working on a piece of code to be reactive from non-reactive. And while fixing the unit tests I have a scenario, I am unsure how to properly replace the logic. Below is an example of current mocking

```
MyClass2 mockResult = mock(MyClass.class);

doNothing().when(mockResult).api1("testing");
when(input.api2(any())).thenReturn(mockResult);

verify(input).api2(any());
verify(mockResult).api1("testing");
```

api2 became reactive now, and the return type is Mono

I simply made changes below

```
MyClass1 input = mock(MyClass1.class);
Mono<MyClass2> mockResult = Mono.just(mock(MyClass.class));

doNothing().when(mockResult).api1("testing"); //  not sure how to test it
when(input.api2(any())).thenReturn(mockResult);

verify(input).api2(any());
verify(mockResult).api1("testing"); //  not sure how to test it. I get Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. Wanted but not invoked: error on trying with block(), which is not right anyway
```

Any suggestions, please

Answer (score 1):

See the `StepVerifier` tool from `reactor-test`: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#testing.

There is just no reason to mock `Mono` or `Flux`.

Also your assumption are wrong in the current code: you try to interact with an object which is not a mock - `Mono.just(mock(MyClass.class))`.

Anyway, try `StepVerifier` and see if you can get rid of mocks at all.

Comment: yes, I have used StepVerifier at other applicable places, but this one i couldn't find a good way to replace

Comment: Well, it must stay as it was: `MyClass2 mockResult = mock(MyClass.class);`. Then you do `Mono<MyClass2> mono = Mono.just(mock(MyClass.class));` and `when(input.api2(any())).thenReturn(mono);` The rest I believe remains the same. I guess your test is much complicated than you show us, so it is hard to determine a context and necessity of such a redundant test...